# How to delay DB query and ignore requests that happen in between with JS?

Tags: javascript, mysql, express, timeout, quill

I am using Quill as a rich text editor for my Node / Express web app.

Quill API has a method called "on" (https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#on) to fire an event every time the editor selection or text changes.

I am using this method to save the contents of the editor to a MySQL database, using `quill.root.innerHTM` to capture the entirety of the content in HTML format.

This works well, but my problem is that this approach fires a POST request to my Express endpoint for every keystroke of the user. I don't want to overwhelm the server and I don't need to save every keystroke variation.

One solution I imagined was to delay the DB query by 3 seconds and fire only one request with the most recent content of the editor.

I tried using `setTimeout()` to achieve this like so:

```
app.post('/editor', (req, res) => {
  let post = true;
  const id = req.query.id;
  const data = req.body.content;

  setTimeout(() => {
    if (post == true) {
      post = false;
      db.connection.query('UPDATE my_table SET content = ? WHERE id = ?', [data, id], (error) => {
        if (error) {
          res.status(500).send("Internal server error")
        }
        res.status(200).send();
      });
    }
    console.log('data posted');
  }, 3000);

});
```

As you can see, I tried using a boolean. I know why this code doesn't work, but I couldn't figure out a way to "ignore" the requests that happen between the time intervals, and only fire a DB query with the latest data from the editor.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar with quill, but at first glance it seems you could set a flag to 1 when a character is typed, and create an interval (`setInterval()`) that runs every X seconds to send the query if the flag is set (and then reset the flag)

Comment: timers/timeouts/intervals are not the right solution here. The simple solution is to throttle your sever calls by counting characters until x number (you choose) have been entered. The counter variable would be set to 0 outside the event handler and incremented inside. Once the magic count is reached, send the server request and reset the counter to 0.

Comment: Thank you for the comments! I'm not sure waiting for x number of characters would work well. The user could stop typing after a certain number which is not multiple of X, resulting in the last characters not being saved. I think I would still need to have some sort of timeout or interval to save the remaining characters.

Comment: I am now looking at a solution using a "debounce" function like the one in this library http://underscorejs.org/#debounce

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem using "debounce" from Underscore.js (http://underscorejs.org/#debounce). It works really well!

I did not touch the server route. I implemented it on the frontend. Here's what the code looks like now:

```
        const quill = new Quill('#editor', options);

        function update() {
          let quillHtml = quill.root.innerHTML;
          let quillContent = {
            "contents": `${quillHtml}`
          };
          postData('/editor', id, quillContent);
        }

        const lazyUpdate = debounce(update, 1000);

        quill.on('text-change', lazyUpdate);
```

postData() is just a helper function to generate a POST request using fetch()